# What is the best online javascript/css/html/xhtml/dom reference?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, xhtml

I'm a front-end developer and I was looking for opinions about the best all-round online documentation for javascript/css/html/xhtml/dom/browser quirks and support. I've tried Sitepoint, Quirksmode, W3Schools but all of these seem to be lacking in certain aspects and have been using them in combination.

Comment: I've compiled all of these and more into a topic-linked list - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823718/best-reference-sites-for-html-and-javascript-programming

Comment: "..looking for opinions about the best.." on Stack-overflow might lead to hazardous community behavior such has judgments, personal notices and other 'flavored' statements, but it's a good question.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like <strike>gotapi.com</strike> (Update 2: Site is apparently offline -- Use another resource such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/))

**Update:** the original answer was from 2008 -- today I would say to check out [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) (as many others have also said).

Comment: looks good but it uses w3schools (a for profit resource) which has a bad reputation - http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Is this site still getting maintained? There doesn't seem to be much recent activity. Also, check out their other interface: http://start.gotapi.com

Comment: Site is no longer active it seems :-/ Shame, I remember it being good & fast. What is the thing to do with answers that have lost their relevance?

Comment: It was getting downvoted which is good for when things are out of date. I updated the post to include a better API reference. I could alternatively remove the gotapi link but I wanted to keep the original answer in tact.

Answer (score 21):

I like Mozilla's references:

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM

These are not at all the one stop site you want, but they help me.

Answer (score 5):

You've actually hit the nail on the head in your description. There is no single website that'll provide you with the detail you seek in every one of those facets.

I find these three are incredibly useful when starting on a blank page: [Mozilla DOM Reference](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) (for general js syntax, etc), [w3schools x/html reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) (look up uncommon attributes!) and [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) (cross-browser js/style details). These are quite highly ranked so look for their urls if you're searching for something specific.

As for specific browser quirks, your best bet is to handle these as they come up and develop skills for googling for answers efficiently. Lots of browser quirks have many variables that go into what you actually end up seeing and how developed a 'solution' is for a specific quirk depends on how much time someone has spent investigating it. Read a bunch of search results and see if the problems are all similar or completely separate. Then, refine your search!

Answer (score 4):

Go straight to W3C docs. They're a bit cryptic at times, but they're solid documentation.

For quirks, obviously sites like Quirksmode are good. But only once you've read actual W3C documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Sitepoint has a very [comprehensive guide to CSS](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css)

Answer (score 3):

The same reference which is included in the Aptana IDE is online... just found this... it's really good:

CSS
http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/CSS.index.html

HTML
http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTML.index.html

HTML DOM O
http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTMLDOM0.index-frame.html

HTML DOM 1 & 2
http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTMLDOM2.index-frame.html

JavaScript Keywords
http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/JSKeywords.index.html

JavaScript Core
http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/JSCore.index-frame.html

Answer (score 2):

I like w3schools for html or simple questions.

For Javascript, I find [Mozilla Developer Center](http://developer.mozilla.org/En) to be pretty useful: [Core Javascript 1.5 Reference](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference)

Comment: I wish w3schools was a little more careful with what they write about Javascript. I understand it's aimed at beginners, but some things are just plain misleading (as an example, look at http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_variables.asp where it claims that `x = 5` and `var x = 5` have the same effect)

Comment: @kangax what's the difference? (I just completed chapters 1 and 2 of wrox beginning javascript, and it didn't mention any difference that I can see), apart from that one is an explicit declaration and the other an implicit declaration, but i don't see a difference in effect

Comment: @barlop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript/1471738#1471738

Answer (score 1):

zvon.org

http://reference.sitepoint.com/

Answer (score 1):

[blooberry.com](http://blooberry.com) is a great HTML/CSS reference site.

Comment: I really like this one too. It has some very good documentation on browser quirks/support for each element. It's too bad Brian hasn't updated the site since 2003.

Answer (score 1):

[devguru.com](http://devguru.com)

Comment: I think DevGuru is very good. It is very fast to get a good overview of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I rely on http://quirksmode.org/resources.html for information on HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  This resource does a great job addressing cross-browser compatibility issues in a helpful table format.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful for some javascript functions http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 0):

I tend to go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/ first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good german reference (and french I think) at [selfhtml.org](http://selfhtml.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going through these [JavaScript Video Lectures](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/learning-javascript-programming-language-through-video-lectures/) (15 of them).

Answer (score 0):

GotAPI is a fantastic resource http://www.gotapi.com

Answer (score 0):

http://www.selfhtml.org/ is in German (originally) and French (translated). English translation has been unfortunately suspended: http://en.selfhtml.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommended w3schools.com. It's a pretty good and comprehensive library, I find.

Answer (score 0):

I always start with [www.zvon.org](http://www.zvon.org), especially the [references](http://www.zvon.org/index.php?nav_id=references&mime=html) section. Provides a good overview and links directly to the corresponding standards.

Answer (score 0):

- [javascriptkit.com/jsref/](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/) (convenient **JavaScript** reference with examples)
- javascriptkit.com/domref/ (**DOM** reference with examples)