# What JavaScript functions are supported by different browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I want to know which sites can give me information on the list of JavaScript functions that are supported by IE/Firefox/Opera/Safari.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918/what-is-the-best-online-javascript-css-html-xhtml-dom-reference

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at **[quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/)**

and in the **[Compatibility Master Table](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)**

you will get a detailed listing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not a direct answer to this question, but never-the-less I think this is useful to know about: You can use the [Sputnik JavaScript Conformance tool](http://sputnik.googlelabs.com/) in Google Labs to check ECMAScript conformance in browsers:

> Sputnik is a JavaScript conformance
>   test suite containing over 5000 tests.
>   It tests how well a JavaScript
>   implementation adheres to the ECMA-262
>   specification version 5, looking only
>   at those features that were also
>   present in the previous version,
>   version 3, and not the new features
>   added in version 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sites for that but you'll probably find that none are absolutely complete, so it is worth checking out each of them

- [quirksmode.org compatibility tables](http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)
- [sitepoint JS reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/) (work in progress)
- [Mozilla MDC reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript) (mozilla only but worth mentioning)

Answer (score 0):

This looks useful http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/